# Clear contents from matched column of data in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I have a column of email addresses on sheet 2 col A (but I could put them on sheet 1 if it would make it easier / faster) that I want to remove from sheet 1 col D if matched (there may be 2 or more occurrences of the same email to be removed/cleared and 1000s of rows in each sheet).

After all day searching forums I'm getting more confused & can't find what I'm looking for. Not sure whether to use .match or .find & .ClearContents & the syntax for iterating through.

Comment: +1 good first question, well done for making your own research first. Do you have to use match or find, or do you just want something which works?

Answer (score 0):

Your post is tagged with VBa, and as such, this macro will do it. But, I didn't use the match or find as you mentioned, I'm not sure if you had to use those or not, I've assumed not and you're just showing what you've attempted.

As always with macros, save your work first, create a copy of the file, and then apply it (just in case it doesn't do what you wanted it means you have a back up)

```
Sub RemoveEmails()

Dim row As Integer
row = 1

Dim sheet_A_Column As String
sheet_A_Column = "D"   ' UPDATE ME IF NEEDED. I am the column of emails in the main table. You will be deleting emails from this list

Dim sheet_B_Column As String
sheet_B_Column = "A" ' UPDATE ME IF NEEDED.  I am the list of emails which need to be matched for deletion. 

Do While (True) ' don't ever stop me! I loop forever...

Dim theValue As String
theValue = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(sheet_B_Column & row).Value ' the value on Sheet2 (the delete list)

If theValue = "" Then
    Exit Do ' unless I run out of things to loop through, at which point, exit
End If

'Now to loop through all the cells on Sheet1 to see which value(s) need clearing or not
For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(sheet_A_Column & ":" & sheet_A_Column).Cells
     If c.Value = theValue Then
            c.Value = ""
      End If
Next

row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

So, a few screen shots to help explain.

The list of emails on Sheet2 which are what we want to remove from sheet1

[image]

Now, Sheet1, the actual list where we want to remove some of them.

[image]

And the final result after running the macro

[image]

I have to admit, the code I've given isn't the most efficient but, based upon your question, it does what it needs!

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty simple workaround to this. Excel's REMOVE DUPLICATE logic is to remove the duplicate that appears lower in the spreadsheet.

If you would like to remove all the items from sheet 2 that appear in sheet 1, simply paste the items from sheet 2 at the top of sheet 1, run the REMOVE DUPLICATE functions for the column, and then delete all the items from sheet 2.

Easy as that.